# Auth::user is not preserved on redirect

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware, laravel-5

After I updated from laravel 5.1 to 5.2 I got this unexpected problem. I use `Auth::login` to manually login the user. And when I redirect user is not preserved.

All the config was gracefully ported from from clear laravel 5.2 installation.

Here's the routes code:

```php
Route::group([ 'middleware' => [ 'web' ] ], function () {
    Route::get('test', function () {
        $user = \Upping\Models\User::find(311);
        Auth::login($user);
        Auth::check(); // true
        return redirect('authCheck');
    });

    Route::get('authCheck', function () {
        Auth::check(); // false
    });
});
```

config\auth.php -> providers

```php
'users' => [
    'driver' => 'eloquent',
    'model' => \Upping\Models\User::class,
],
```

*Speaking of laravel experience, tiny hint should be enough for me. And thanks for helping out.*

Comment: It's unlikely to be the redirect that's breaking things. Check that your sessions are working.

Comment: Is domain exactly the same (before and after redirection) - both with www or without www? What happens if you don't make this redirection and go to `authCheck` url? Is it also `false` ?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek 1) Domain is exactly the same (both without www).
2) Direct access to `authCheck` gives me `false` as well.

Comment: @ceejayoz yes, I'm quite sure the issue is related to sessions. Though the core of evil is missing my attention.

Config is plain default and everything worked just fine before update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the real cause was a bit far-fetched. I read error logs and figured it was Zend Z-ray and its laravel plugin being mean to 5.2 update.

After i turned the thing off everything began to operate properly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you put all your routes inside:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
  // here your routes
});
```

? If not, you should do it, because in Laravel 5.2 Session are started for `web` group middleware by default. See [Routing documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#basic-routing) for details

**EDIT**

If it's not the case - I see you use custom User class `\Upping\Models\User` that you use for login. Have you set the same class in `config/auth.php`  in `providers -> users -> model` ?

Comment: No, that's definitely not the case. I updated my post. Sorry for hiding the information.

Comment: I added the section to the question. That doesn't seem to be the case. User class uses updated traits. And I can get the user after I Auth::login one. Not after redirect though.